# Purpose of the function with the contract's name?

Tags: solidity, constructor

What is the purpose of the `WithdrawalContract` function in this case? If `becomeRichest` doing exactly same but with a certain condition and adding a pending withdrawal to the `pendingWithdrawals`.

[image: code snippet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the constructor function. It only executes once, i.e. at the creation/ deployment time of the contract.

Here in this case, at the creation/ deployment of the contract, it sets the `richest` to be the one who is deploying the contract and the `mostSent` to be the value sent at the time of deploying.

The name of the contract is used as the constructor function only in earlier releases. As here name of contract is `WithdrawalContract` and the constructor is `WithdrawalContract()` as the version says `solidity ^0.4.11`. Now - the latest is `solidity ^.0.4.24` - this is being deprecated and uses the `constructor()` function.

You can read the documentation [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#creating-contracts) for the latest version.

> When a contract is created, its constructor (a function declared with
>   the constructor keyword) is executed once.

And in the documentation [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.11/contracts.html#creating-contracts) for the version `0.4.11` describes your case,

> Contracts can be created “from outside” or from Solidity contracts.
>   When a contract is created, its constructor (a function with the same
>   name as the contract) is executed once.

This change has been introduced in the version `0.4.22` - as per the release notes [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.22),

> Constructors should now be defined using `constructor(uint arg1, uint
>   arg2) { ... }` to make them stand out and avoid bugs when contracts
>   are renamed but not their constructors.

Comment: Is it automatically calls? Why? It's not a constructor. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: yes, it get automatically called when the contract is deployed and it is the constructor. Did you read my quotes from the documentations?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't note that the contract has the same name as a function.